# Использование переменной в другом классе

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Я вот даже не знаю как сформулировать вопрос... Мне нужно из одного класса взять переменную для 2го класса, но сделать я это не могу =( почему не знаю. Мне плохо даеться наследование, или что это вообще такое.

Помогите еси сможете.

У меня есть класс, маленький **CellFront** (не мой)

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"front-bkg" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
        UIImageView *bkgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

        CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 280.0, 1.0);
        cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        cellLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        cellLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cellLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self addSubview:bkgView];
        [self addSubview:cellLabel];
        [bkgView release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Все что он делает это создает ячейку.

У меня есть другой класс **QuoteTabeViewController**, где я делаю метод **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

Мне нужно достать **cellLabel** и использовать его в моем классе **QuoteTabeViewController**

Что б не показаться совсем глупым я пытался достать его вот таким способом 
`[CellFront [cellLabel sizeToFit]];` 
Но у меня ничего не заработало, наверное не удивительно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите метод в `CellFront`, который вернет ваш  `cellLabel`

```
 - (UILabel*) getCellLabel{
    return cellLabel;
}
```

И если у вас есть указатель на экземпляр класса `CellFront *myCellFont;` то вы его можете получить `UILabel *label = [myCellFont getCellLabel]`

[details](http://www.imaladec.com/lessons/interfejs_klassa/)

---

Или добавьте property в @interface CellFront

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel* cellLabel
```

Получить его можно таким-же методом, как и выше

[details](http://www.imaladec.com/lessons/svojstva_i_metodi_dostupa/)

Вообще, для новичков я рекомендую этот [сайт](http://www.imaladec.com), особенно уроки. А так-же читать [книги](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118282/) по этому направлении.

Comment: Спасибо,  помогло!

Comment: Ну конечно свойство, какой еще getCellLabel, это не соответствует конвенциям.

Comment: не соответствует конвенции только название метода.

Comment: Я это и имел ввиду.